# Asp.Net: dynamically created controls stop working after first PostBack

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls, postback

I have a page that creates a list, a button and a textfield dynamically in the Page_Load handler. When you click the button, the text from the textbox is added to the list and everything is re-created by clearing the controls collection of the page and then re-adding all required controls.
So basically, the button gets created two times for every Postback (first in the Page_Load, then in the Button_Click handler).

This only works on the first PostBack. If you try it a second time, the Button_Click handler never gets called (although the dynamic controls get re-created on PostBack).
What am I missing here? Is it possible that the Button_Click event is still wired-up to the first button (the one that was thrown away via `Controls.Clear()` )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out what the cause of the problem is: when the controls are created more than once, the Event-Handlers (e.g. Button.Click) are also registered more than once. I don't know why, but this causes all of them to stop working. In other words, the events of the disposed Buttons somehow interfer with the events of the actual Buttons.
I solved this by ensuring that the handlers are only registered once (in the Page_Load).

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load is too late to create the button; it should be in Page init or preinit.  If you readd the button, after clearing it, you have to readd the event handler too.

Comment: I have tried it with Page_Init. The controls get properly recreated, but the Button_Click still isn't working on a second PostBack...